# How to access class variable inside methods of that class in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

- Operating System: Windows, 64bit
- Python Version: 3.7.11
- IDE: Jupyter Notebook (with conda env)

I have below code:

```
class Vocabulary(object):
    
    PAD_token = 0
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.index2word = {PAD_token: "PAD"}

# create object
voc = Vocabulary()
```

I want to use `PAD_token`  class variable inside `__init__` method but I got below error:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_8472/897996601.py in <module>
----> 1 voc = Vocabulary()

~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_8472/3780152240.py in __init__(self)
      4 
      5     def __init__(self):
----> 6         self.index2word = {PAD_token: "PAD", SOS_token: "SOS", EOS_token: "EOS"}

NameError: name 'PAD_token' is not defined
```

Question:

- How can I use `PAD_token` class variable inside `__init__` or other methods of the class?

Comment: self.PAD_token will work

Comment: Also defining variables this way makes it shared between all instances of that class, so watch out. (You don',t even have to initialize an instance to access it, it becomes static)

Comment: @Ahmed AEK This is exactly what I want. I want that all instances access the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to access it

first: `self.__class__.PAD_token`

second: `self.PAD_token`

If you just need to access class variables, the first one is recommended

Comment: It will be all right. as long as you use it after the class is created.

Comment: The first one is recommended by who, and for what reason?

Comment: `self.__class__.PAD_token` will go directly to the class namespace to find.

`self.PAD_token` will first go to self's namespace to find, if not found, it will go to class to find

Comment: Of course, the choice of this depends on the specific situation. Sometimes if the PAD_token of different instances is different, `self.PAD_token` is preferred instead of `self.__class__PAD_token`

Comment: @kaya3 I recommend first because If just need to access class variables

Answer (score 1):

To access any class variable from within the object, you need to put `self.` in front of the variable name.

This means that to call `PAD_token` you need to use `self.PAD_TOKEN`

Your code should look like this.

```
class Vocabulary(object):
    
    PAD_token = 0
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.index2word = {self.PAD_token: "PAD"}

# create object
voc = Vocabulary()
```

If you do not add the `self` it will think you are trying to access a local variable named `PAD_token`, and there isn't a local variable that has been defined within that method with that name, that is why it is throwing that not defined error.

Answer (score 0):

write it with self keyword like self.PAD_token.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying access variable that you assigned in your class.
Here PAD_token can be called as [class variable](https://careerkarma.com/blog/python-class-variables/).

you can access it by class name **Vocabulary.PAD_token** or by self **self.PAD_token**.

In your case dictionary will place its value to the key
i.e.

```
{0:"PAD"} #ignoring other keys
```

because you have assigned that to 0 in initialization.