Does accessing a class variable by class in instance methods cause problems?
I have seen multiple posts on this - some are quite old and some are not so old. So, I thought of asking the question again as pylint issues warnings on some of the accepted answers from previous posts like https://stackoverflow.com/a/70422556/214526
class Foo:
  _THRESHOLD_VAL: float = 0.8
  
  def __init__(self, value: float):
    self._val = value

  def method1(self):
    if self._val < self.__class__._THRESHOLD_VAL:
       print("less than threshold")
    else:
       print("more than or equal to threshold")

The default way to access a class variable is self.<var_name> but are there reasons not to use self.__class__.<var_name>?
An advantage of using self.__class__.<var_name> is that it explicitly says that a class variable being used. However, "pylint" issues the following warning -
warning: Access to a protected member _THRESHOLD_VAL of a client class
What are the actual risks, and reasons not to use self.__class__.<var_name>? How should I avoid or prevent the warning from arising?

.__class__._THRESHOLD_VAL is definitely the worse between the two for me, but this whole thing is opinion based and off-topic on SO.

I'm not a python expert, but if protected means the same thing as it does in other languages, you're supposed to access  it through either its corresponding property, or through an inheritance relationship.

@RobertHarvey - in this case, it is being used in the same class; not being accessed in different class hierarchy

The error is because of the leading underscore that makes this a private variable. You get the warning because private variables should be accessed on Foo objects, but __class__ is a type object. Remove the underscore and the warning goes away - but its still bad because it breaks inheritance (I think...)

I have never seen self.__class__._THRESHOLD_VAL.  Class variables are accessed from instance methods using self and from class methods using cls.

@tdelaney If I remove the leading '_', how to convey the user code that they are not supposed to use it?

@soumeng78 - right. Use self._THRESHOLD_VAL.

@FrankYellin - please refer to the stackoverflow link which recommends this usage.

@FrankYellin It's pretty common to see something like self.__class__.__name__ to access class name within instance method, but I agree this is less common knowledge and not everyone know about this access pattern.

Okay, I may have been too hasty on that "breaks inheritance" part.

@rv.kvetch.  That's true.  But typically foo stuff have their own rules.  I don't self.__name__ even works.

Instead of asking for recommendations and stating a preference, you should try to ask more direct questions. Like how to prevent or avoid the warning, what the reasoning for the warning is, or what happens in a specific use case and why.

@rv.kvetch Sure, for special fields like __name__ it's strictly necessary, but I agree with Frank: I've never seen an explicit __class__ used to access class variables. The __class__, to me, is always an indicator that something exciting and meta is happening (mucking with MROs, generating classes on the fly, making a custom dataclass decorator, etc.), and using a blunt instrument like that for something simple and ordinary like class variables would make me look twice.

The pylint error is probably a false positive for a generic self.whatever._attr which is bad, because you shouldn't use attributes that are prefixed with an underscore, because conventionally, they are not part of the public API. In this case though, you are accessing your own class attribute. normally, whatever is some other type, i.e. a client class. In this case, it isn't

If you feel a question's answers are outdated, the proper course of action is to post a bounty on that question looking for updated answers.

You only have to look at this:
class A:
    _x = 1

    def fun(self):
        return self._x, self.__class__._x

    @classmethod
    @property
    def x(cls):
        return cls._x


class B(A):
    ...


class C(A):
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = 2

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x


a, b, c = A(), B(), C()
print(a.fun(), a.x, a.__class__.x)
print(b.fun(), b.x, b.__class__.x)
print(c.fun(), c.x, c.__class__.x)

And the output:
(1, 1) 1 1
(1, 1) 1 1
(2, 1) 2 <property object at 0x00000221DA753C40>

... to see that most of this can have unexpected consequences. And from Python 3.13, the wrapping of a property in a class method will no longer work: https://docs.python.org/3.13/library/functions.html#classmethod
Accessing a class attribute doesn't need to go through __class__ and shouldn't be performed in that way because it circumvents normal inheritance logic. You may argue that you want this circumvention, in which case someone might argue that - since you're breaking the rules - exception annotations for linters should be part of your code as well.

but the linter is just wrong here, it isn't a client class.

That's a valid point, although that might be a limitation of pylint, in combining the error for accessing the class attribute through __class__ with the error for when the protected class attribute is accessed from outside the inheritance tree? That's getting a bit deeper into the inner workings of pylint though - if that's an issue, it should be reported as an issue to the maintainers of pylint. I don't think it affects the answer, unless you see something specifically wrong with it?
